# Mule Merge HTTP response message

Tags: mule, mule-flow

I am using MULE and  3 transformers, 2 that that require information from an HTTP response + a POJO. Transformer 2 and 3 only get the HTTP POST repsonse now and not the POJO.

Transformer1 gets a POJO and transforms it , sends it to a HTTP endpoint, it uses a Post request.

The response of the POST is used in transformer 2 and 3, however they
also need the POJO that to do their transformation !

How can I use the pojo that was used in Transformer 1 + the http response in transformer
2 and 3? I want a message to enter the ALL control flow with the payload = http response + the POJO.

Is it possible to add the two in a message e.g 2 payloads in 1 message ? How can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Mule Flow: 
[image: http://i57.tinypic.com/15s33x1.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the original POJO payload as a message property to access it later in the flow. See here for an introduction to the Mule message property scopes:

http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-school-the-mulemessage-property-scopes-and-variables/

Comment: Thanks I tried store the POJO in a message outbound properties using the transformer Message properties. However the inbound properties did not contain the pojo in step 'Object to string', I resolved my issue using the Variable Transformer:         <set-variable variableName="VAR" value="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>. To acces it in a custom java transformer I used : message.getProperty("VAR", PropertyScope.INVOCATION

Comment: You probably slightly misunderstood the above blog (it should be more explicit). Outbound properties being transformed into inbound properties refers to communication between Mule flows, not behavior inside a single flow. In the case of HTTP calls, Mule automatically transforms outbound properties into HTTP headers, and all HTTP headers received by Mule will likewise be available as inbound properties.